# Select Maximum, using filelds from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a database `Library`, which has a lot of tables and we need 3 tables for query:

- Table `Librarians`: ID, Surname;
- Table `StudentCard`: ID, foreign key on table Librarians and other columns which we don't use
- Table `TeacherCard`: ID, foreign key on table Librarians and other columns  which we don't use

Query: select the librarian's surname, which gave the most count of books.

I know, how to resolve, when I took data only from one table, e. g. TeacherCard

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    Librarians.LastName, MAX(Librarians.CountOfBooks) AS Books 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         L.LastName, COUNT(*) AS CountOfBooks 
     FROM Libs L, T_Cards T
     WHERE T.Id_Lib IN (SELECT L.Id)
     GROUP BY L.LastName) AS Librarians
GROUP BY 
    Librarians.LastName
ORDER BY 
    MAX(Librarians.CountOfBooks) DESC
GO
```

I don't know, how to use data from `TeacherCard` and from `StudetnCard` at the same time.

Please, help to write this query.

Comment: I think you can use [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx), it would be good think if you can create [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some data so we can solve it there, it shouldn't be so hard...

Answer (score 0):

I have a right resolving !!!!

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.Name, B.CountOut
FROM
(SELECT A.Name, SUM(A.Count) AS CountOut
FROM 
(SELECT Libs.LastName AS Name, COUNT(S_Cards.DateOut) AS [Count]
FROM Libs JOIN S_Cards ON S_Cards.Id_Lib = Libs.Id
GROUP BY Libs.LastName
UNION ALL
SELECT Libs.LastName AS Name, COUNT(T_Cards.DateOut) AS [Count]
FROM Libs JOIN T_Cards ON T_Cards.Id_Lib = Libs.Id
GROUP BY Libs.LastName) AS A
GROUP BY A.Name ) AS B
ORDER BY B.CountOut DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another right answer:

```
SELECT TOP 2 LastName, COUNT (*) [count] FROM
(SELECT LastName FROM Libs L, S_Cards S
WHERE S.id_lib = L.id
UNION ALL
SELECT LastName FROM Libs L, T_Cards T
WHERE T.id_lib = L.id) As Res
GROUP By LastName 
ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC
```